# In Lightroom, how do I see which presets have been applied to an image?

Tags: software, lightroom, lightroom-3

In Adobe Lightroom, multiple presets can be applied to an image. Is there a way to see which presets have been applied to an image?

Comment: Have you checked the History section?

Answer (score 4):

History of image changes, including presets applied, should be in the history panel.

[image]

Comment: You can also see if any changes have occurred at all by the icon in the gallery view. Different purposes, but same idea kind of.